# Why doesn't stack exchange/overflow send inactive users a mail?

Tags: feature-request, email

Considering my own experience that I became a member to ask a question more then a year ago. After posting the question I never returned untill just a few weeks ago. Now I have a better understanding of how reputation works I wonder why I was never reminded for the following:

> you haven't logged in for some time and you have some notifications

---

**Update**:

After reading the answers/comments I think I hit a soft spot. I understand we shouldn't spam users, but consider a new user who asks a question and then forgets he even registered, not the users who already gained some reputation. And never even reads the answer.

Comment: Many users here are busy people and enjoy being left alone by SO. This would be breaking that principle

Comment: RE your updates: All the answers and comments are completely reasonable and are delivered in a reserved, professional tone. What "soft spot" are you referring to?

Comment: I liked @Makoto 's answer, because he gave an answer about the amount of mails to be send. Most of the others are about bothering or spamming people and preferences which can be edited in settings. My goal was to keep valuable people (marketing what SO is about), not just a one time hit and run, which was for me the first time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To add on to some of the existing answers, "inactivity" is a bit of a moving target.  For some, it's the last time that they logged in.  For others, it's whether or not they've got more than 1 rep.

I don't have a lot of time today to delve into the numbers, but [depending on how you slice inactivity](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/397930/inactive-user-spread), there are anywhere between 1.9M and 2.9M inactive accounts on the site.  Note that those only take into account 1-rep users and would not factor in users that *have* more rep and just haven't been around in a while.

Sending out that volume of emails is impractical and useless, since it wouldn't accomplish the intended goal of getting the inactive users back into the fold, and would only serve to get Stack Exchange blocked or severely throttled from sending out emails.

Answer (score 17):

TL;DR: Stack Overflow is not Facebook.

If you enable email notifications in your Stack Exchange settings, you will receive email notifications for updates on the sites, comments, edits, chat messages and the like. Example:

> The following item was added to your Stack Exchange global inbox since
>   you last checked it on 2015-05-18:
>
> - foo
> - baz
> - bar

This is network-wide, meaning you're notified of activity any of your SE accounts. I think that is quite enough. SE does not need to send out unsolicited emails and spam people's inbox.

Comment: +1 for `Stack Overflow is not Facebook`

Answer (score 10):

Stack Overflow has historically avoided reaching out to users through E-Mail when that hasn't been actively requested.

One of the reasons is that the site is so strongly built on voluntary contributions of "slices of time" *whenever the user wants to contribute them*. Stack Overflow is a massive MMORPG which you can log into, and out of, whenever you want - the only exception being moderators, who should be able to spend (on average) at least 30 minutes a day on the site to make an impact, and of course paid employees.

Sending them reminders about how long they've been absent or inactive would be breaking with that tradition of respectfulness for the user's time.

Comment: "Stack Overflow is a massive MMORPG" = brilliant.

Answer (score 4):

All email-notifications SE might send you are strictly opt-in, and easily canceled.

That's because they aren't spammers, and aren't very keen to be mistaken as such low-lifes.

Also see: [How to send 100,000 emails weekly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905734/how-to-send-100-000-emails-weekly)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how the link you've provided aids the question...

Comment: Just to emphasize that sending unsolicited emails is a good way to make many people angry fast, and subsequently have problems sending *any* emails.